# Angular chart set min max value not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

I am currently working on a line graph and below is the screenshot of it:
[image]

I wanted to set the min and max value for the y-axis of the graph.
After looking over the internet for solutions and tried, but still it's not working and the console shows no error. Can you help me to spot where I did wrong?
[image]

Comment: min max value for what?

Comment: Sorry for not specifying clear enough, I will update the post. I wanted to set the min and max value for the line graph i have and the commented parts are the testings i did but all of them are not working.

Comment: can you create a js fiddle to reprouce the issue

Comment: i cant create a jiddle because the readings are read from a JSON file in my computer. Its just the min and max in the $scope.option not changing anything towards my graph